# Couldn't add firebase storage download url in same firestore document in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to upload multiple images to firebase storage and store those urls in one firestore document as an array of strings, but I couldn't add all urls in same firestore document. Instead it's creating different documents for each firebase storage Url.

ImageUpload.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { db, storage } from "../firebase.config";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import {collection ,addDoc ,arrayUnion ,FieldValue ,updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";

function ImageUpload() {
  const [allImages, setAllImages] = useState([]);

  function handleAllImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setAllImages(e.target.files);
    console.log(e.target.files);
  }

  function MutipleUpload(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const docRef = collection(db, "products");

      {
        for (let i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {

          const storageRef = ref(storage, `productImages/${allImages[i].name}`);
          const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, allImages[i], {
            contentType: allImages[i].type,
          });

          uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
              const progress =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
              console.log(progress);
            },
            (error) => toast.error(error.message),
            () => {
              getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(
                async (downloadURL) => {
                  await addDoc(docRef, {
                    imgUrl: arrayUnion(downloadURL),
                  });
                }
              );
            }
          );
        }
      }
      toast.success("product added successfully!");
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="file"
        multiple="multiple"
        onChange={handleAllImage}
        required
      />
      <button onClick={MutipleUpload} type="submit" className="buy__btn mt-3">
        Add Image
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default ImageUpload;
```

Extra text cause error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: The details you should include are what you want the code to do instead of what it does now.  If you describe the result you want, then someone can help. "But couldn't add all urls in same firestore document" is a bit vague - what does a document look like that has all the URLs in it?  An array field? Different fields for each URL?  Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I have clearly added what I want the code to do in the description  “Trying to upload multiple images to firebase storage and store those urls in one firestore document as an array of strings.
But couldn't add all urls in same firestore document. 
Instead it's creating different documents for each firebase storage Url.“ Isn’t this enough? Dough Stevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(
  async (downloadURL) => {
    await addDoc(docRef, {
      imgUrl: arrayUnion(downloadURL),
    });
  }
);
```

Every time you call `addDoc`, Firestore create a new document in the collection.

If you instead want [update an existing document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data), you have to:

1. Remember the document ID for the document you want to update.
2. Then call `updateDoc` on that document

To generate a document ID once and then update that all the time, have a look at the third code snippet in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call doc():
>
> ```
> import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
>
> // Add a new document with a generated id
> const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));
>
> // later...
> await setDoc(newCityRef, data);
> ```

Applied to your use-case, that could look *something like* this:

```
const docRef = collection(db, "products");
const newDocRef = doc(docRef); //  generate reference to a single new doc

{
  for (let i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `productImages/${allImages[i].name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, allImages[i], {
      contentType: allImages[i].type,
    });

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log(progress);
      },
      (error) => toast.error(error.message),
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(
          async (downloadURL) => {
            await setDoc(newDocRef, { //  Call setDoc, since the doc may not exist yet
              imgUrl: arrayUnion(downloadURL),
            }, { merge: true }); //  tell it to merge values into any existing doc
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure I will try this. Also I would like to know how to change this code to do something like creating a document with some data and update it instead of creating a reference and updating it.